# What causes a program to stuck after a syscall in disassembler view?

Tags: qt, assembly, system-calls, disassembly

I'm developing a desktop application using `QT-Creator`. The project is programmed in `C` and tested with `gtest`. It runs on `Linux (Debian)` machine.

While trying to run the google test, sometimes it gets stuck in disassembler code as following:

```
0x7ffff780e16b                   0f 94 c0           sete   %al
0x7ffff780e16e                   eb 0f              jmp    0x7ffff780e17f
0x7ffff780e170                   be 80 00 00 00     mov    $0x80,%esi
0x7ffff780e175                   45 30 c0           xor    %r8b,%r8b
0x7ffff780e178                   b8 ca 00 00 00     mov    $0xca,%eax
0x7ffff780e17d                   0f 05              syscall
0x7ffff780e17f                   8b 3c 24           mov    (%rsp),%edi
```

Everytime it gets stuck, I find it in the last line of the disassembler code. I've no clue what is it about but obviously it has something to do with `syscall`. I tried to jump to its equivalent C code but there isn't any. I think it has something to do with startup code or so, but I'm not sure.

Any idea what can cause this problem and in which directions I have to check?

Note: My project is a multi-thread project and I use a lot of pointers in it. I did my best to protect shared resources with mutexes.

Comment: "Note: My project is a multi-thread project and I use a lot of pointers in it" make sure you protect data accessed from different threads with a mutex

Comment: This appears to be a call to `futex` with op = `FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE`.

Comment: Then it is probably a deadlock...

Comment: @Erlkoenig is there a way to check if it really is?

Comment: Try compiling with `-fsanitize=thread`, or run with valgrind. You'll have to debug it; examine the stack traces of the running threads to see which mutex the program is trying to acquire, and which mutexes are locked already from where.

Comment: @Erlkoenig I found memory leaks with valgrind. But what does it have to do with deadlock? `A deadlock is a situation wherein two or more competing actions are waiting for the other to finish. As a consequence, neither ever does`. Could you please explain?

Comment: Valgrind is capable of detecting _some_ deadlock conditions. Running your program with valgrind is quick and easy, and if an error is displayed you're lucky; if not, you'll have to resort to "proper" debugging techniques.

Comment: `Sanitize` helped me fixing race conditions and now it works fine. Thanks @Erlkoenig

Comment: Summarized the comments into an answer; would you mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a deadlock. Try compiling with `-fsanitize=thread`, or run with valgrind. You'll have to debug it; examine the stack traces of the running threads to see which mutex the program is trying to acquire, and which mutexes are locked already from where.
Both Valgrind and `-fsanitize=thread` are capable of detecting *some* deadlock conditions. Running your program with valgrind is quick and easy, and if an error is displayed you're lucky; if not, you'll have to resort to "proper" debugging techniques.

As requested, a few details about exactly what's going on:

The disassembly shows a syscall to the [`futex()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) function. This function blocks the current thread until a certain condition is true. If no other thread ever sets this condition, the thread is blocked indefinitely. So what actually happens is that the thread hangs *inside* `syscall`, i.e. at kernel level. The debugger is lying in telling you it is blocking *after* the `syscall`, because it can't know what's happening inside the kernel. Standard thread synchronization mechanisms like `std::mutex` call `futex()` internally, so using these will result in your code invoking `futex()`.

Here is a very simple example where the `threadFun` function always hangs within a `futex()` syscall:

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

void threadFun (std::mutex& m) {
    m.lock ();
}


int main () {
    std::mutex m;

    m.lock ();

    std::thread t (threadFun, std::ref(m));

    t.join ();
}
```

When running it locally via GDB and interrupting the program, you can clearly see the `mov $0xca,%eax` and `syscall` instructions that constitute the futex() call inside the disassembly. The program will hang forever until killed.

How does the `syscall` instruction for `futex()` end up in the generated code?

The C or C++ standard library may also contain (inline) assembly code. In this case, `std::mutex` calls the `pthread` function [`pthread_mutex_lock`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) which is implemented in the glibc [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c#L80), which calls [`__lll_lock_wait`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/nptl/lowlevellock.c#L43) which instantiates [`lll_futex_timed_wait`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/0ad926f34937f7b4843a8b49e5d93199601fe324/sysdeps/nptl/lowlevellock-futex.h#L87) which in turn instantiates [`internal_syscall4`](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/0ad926f34937f7b4843a8b49e5d93199601fe324/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h#L302) which uses inline assembly to produce the `syscall` instruction. Since you probably don't have the glibc debugging symbols and source code installed, the debugger can't see this code and can only show you the disassembly.

However, all these details probably don't help you much in debugging. When interrupting the example program in GDB, the backtrace shows the call to `std::mutex::lock()` from within `threadFun`, which is really all you need to know it's a deadlock: The program requested to wait for something that never happens, and the runtime environment (i.e. C++ standard library + glibc + kernel) comply. How exactly it does that is of little concern. If you write `std::puts(nullptr)` you'll get a crash, and how this exactly happens isn't very important for application development; you have to locate the erroneous call in *your* code.

When you find out that your code hangs inside a locking function such as `std::mutex::lock()`, you know it's probably a deadlock and can then use the aforementioned tools such as `-fsanitize=thread` and `valgrind` to find the actual cause. If these don't help, use the GDB commands `info threads` and `thread X` and `bt` to obtain the backtraces of all threads. By examining these, you should be able to find which thread locked which mutex.

Comment: You have explained how to fix this. Could you please explain what does this dissambly really mean? I mean what is the functionality of this dissambly, why does it hang there, and what is the real code behind it? I'm trying to understand the problem more.

Comment: As Michael commented, this is a syscall to the [`futex()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) function. This function blocks the current thread until a certain condition is true. If no other thread ever sets this condition, the thread is blocked indefinitely. So what actually happens is that the thread hangs _inside_ `syscall`, i.e. at kernel level. The debugger is lying in telling you it is blocking _after_ the `syscall`. Standard thread synchronization mechanisms like `std::mutex` call `futex()` internally.

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/z/YfeMTh) is a very simple example where the `threadFun` function always hangs within a `futex()` syscall. When running it locally via GDB and interrupting the program, you can clearly see the `mov $0xca,%eax` and `syscall` instructions that constitute the `futex()` call inside the disassembly. On the compiler explorer, the program is killed as it exceeds the timeout. Locally, it will hang forever until killed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explaination Erlkoenig. I now understood how did you knew it is a deadlock. But still one point not clear for me. A disassembly usually has a real C code behind it, right? The code that called the `futex()` function is `std::mutex`, right? If yes, why can't I view the original code. It would be easier to debug.

Comment: The C or C++ standard library may also contain (inline) assembly code. In this case, `std::mutex` calls the `pthread` function `pthread_mutex_lock` which is implemented in the glibc [here](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c#L80), which calls [__lll_lock_wait](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/5f72f9800b250410cad3abfeeb09469ef12b2438/nptl/lowlevellock.c#L43) which instantiates [lll_futex_timed_wait](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/0ad926f34937f7b4843a8b49e5d93199601fe324/sysdeps/nptl/lowlevellock-futex.h#L87) ...

Comment: This then instantiates [internal_syscall4](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/0ad926f34937f7b4843a8b49e5d93199601fe324/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sysdep.h#L302) which uses inline assembly to produce the `syscall` instruction. Since you probably don't have the glibc debugging symbols and source code installed, the debugger can't see this code and can only show you the disassembly. However, this information probably doesn't help you much in debugging; the backtrace shows that `threadFun` calls `std::mutex::lock()`, which is really all you need to know it's a deadlock.

Comment: You can then use the aforementioned tools such as `-fsanitize=thread` and `valgrind` to find the actual cause.

Comment: Thanks @Erlkoenig. It's now clear. Maybe it would be very useful if you combin the comments with the answer itself.

Comment: Updated the answer :)